# javax.imageio.ImageIO.read() returns null

Tags: java, oracle, image-processing, blob, javax.imageio

I got this code:

```
java.awt.image.BufferedImage bi = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(attachment.getAttachmentAsBlob().getBinaryStream());
```

Although the `Binary Stream` is `byte array` of 3727458 bytes, the function returns `null`.

My purpose is to get a `Blob` from `Oracle` which is a TIFF image and convert it to PNG, do I have some other alternatives to make it?

Comment: Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied ImageInputStream with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently registered. If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the stream, null is returned.  So perhaps no ImageReader claims to be able to read the stream

Comment: could you please comment a reference to an example of it? an answer would be wonderful.

Comment: Based on some quick googling and the JavaDocs, TIFF is only supported out of the box for Java 9+, previous versions relied on the Java Advanced Imaging API (JAI), or other plug-in